# Unable to bind values after inserting table rows with jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this in my html:

```
<table class="dataTable" id="CADataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Type</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Adress</th>
        <th> ID Number</th>
        <th> Contact</th>
        <th> Note</th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="CAType" id="CAType" data-bind="value: CAType" style="width: 12em;">               
                <option>1</option> 
                <option>2</option>  
                <option>3</option>  
                <option>4</option>      
            </select>
        </td>       
<!--         <td><input type="text" name="CAType" data-bind="value: CAType" style="width: 9em;"></td> -->
        <td><input type="text" name="CAName" data-bind="value: CAName" style="width: 15em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAAdress" data-bind="value: CAAdress" style="width: 15em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAIdNum" data-bind="value: CAIdNum" style="width: 6em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAContact" data-bind="value: CAContact" style="width: 10em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CANote" data-bind="value: CANote" style="width: 15em;"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="export" class="button" data-bind="click: newCreditRows">Add new row</button>
```

and a jquery code inside of a knockout js view model, witch is executed when the button is pressed:

```
var clickAdd = 0;
                        newCreditRows = function(){
                            clickAdd++;
                            if(clickAdd<=9){
                                $('#CADataTable tr:last').after('<tr><td><select name="CAType' +clickAdd+ '" id="CAType' +clickAdd+ '" data-bind="value: CAType' +clickAdd+ '" style="width: 12em;"><option>Съдлъжник</option> <option>Поръчител</option>   <option>3то Лице</option>   <option>ипотекарни / заложни длъжници</option>      </select></td><td><input type="text" name="CAName' +clickAdd+ '" data-bind="value: CAName' +clickAdd+ 
                                  '" style="width: 15em;"></td><td><input type="text" name="CAAdress' +clickAdd+ '" data-bind="value: CAAdress' +clickAdd+ 
                                  ' " style="width: 15em;"></td><td><input type="text" name="CAIdNum' +clickAdd+ ' " data-bind="value: CAIdNum' +clickAdd+ 
                                  '" style="width: 6em;"></td><td><input type="text" name="CAContact' +clickAdd+ '" data-bind="value: CAContact' +clickAdd+ 
                                  ' "style="width: 10em;"></td><td><input type="text" name="CANote' +clickAdd+ '" data-bind="value: CANote' +clickAdd+ '" style="width: 15em;"></td></tr>');                            
                            }else
                                alert("Maximum number reached!");
                            };
```

Everything is working just fine, but what I noticed is that the new rows added by the jquery code can not bind the value to the `ko.observable()` variables (I have everything declared correctly in my viewmodel, I'm not posting it because the code will become huge.)

I mean that the observable `CAAdress1` witch is declared like this in my code: `'" data-bind="value: CAAdress' +clickAdd` is not working.

I'm sure that I'm missing something really small like char escaping, but I'm still too new in jquery and knockout, so I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `delegate` or `on` the events with jquery

Comment: The handlers are bound at initialisation time. Subsequent additions won't have the handlers bound because they didn't exist when the initial code was run. For jQuery you solve this by delegating the handler from an element higher in the DOM tree that's guaranteed to exist. I don't know how that operates in Knockout.

Comment: can you please make more descriptive title? "Strange, but simple jquery issue" have no for people searching for similar issue in future.

Comment: @0lukasz0 is it better now? :)

Comment: @Slim now it's cool, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are injecting html into the dom after you called the applyBindings method.
So Ko is not aware of the new elements.

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cAMz/)

```
var CA = function() {
    this.CAName = null;
    this.CAAdress= null;
    this.CAIdNum = null;
    this.CAContact = null;
    this.CAName = null;
    this.CANote= null;
    this.CAType = null;
};

var vm = {
    newCreditRows : function () {

        this.creditRows.push(new CA());
    },
    creditRows : ko.observableArray()
};


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I hope it helps.